# requestPersonalizationToken returns with SKErrorDomain error 7

Tags: ios, swift, token, apple-musickit

After calling the requestPersonalizationToken method in Apple's MusicKit with our developer token and the completionHandler from the example from Apple, it returns with a nil token and SKErrorDomain error 7. I can't find any documentation about this error and I don't know what could be going wrong since the code is pretty much verbatim from the example code.

Comment: Ditto here. Are you still getting this?

Comment: @MikePollard Yep. I'm going to submit a help request to Apple today and see if they can't help. If I get any more info I'll make sure to put it in this thread.

Comment: Thanks. Found [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82493) about it, people were seeing it early August but said it had been fixed. Certainly not for you or I :(

Comment: Out of interest do you have different iCloud and iTuneStore accounts or a single account?

Comment: I'm not an apple user myself so I had to borrow the phone off of another guy and I don't know about his setup.

Comment: it is due to your icloud account is not connected. or your network connect has issue which is not allowed to verify it.